# Utilizar FormulaR1C1

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Olá, eu gostaria de tirar uma dúvida. O meu código é responsável por ler uma coluna, se o valor encontrado for diferente do anterior, ele adiciona uma linha, pinta de uma cor específica e na coluna de referência escreve “subtotal”.  Minha última tarefa é criar os somatórios mensais na linha que acabou de ser criada. Para tal utilizei FormulaR1C1 mas não consegui uma lógica para fazer esse somatório.

Aqui está o trecho do meu código:

```
Sub criar_linha()

Dim txt As String
Dim endcell, total As Variant
Dim columnsRange As Range


txt = "Cliente"
endcell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Teste").Cells.Find(txt, , ,xlWhole).Address
total = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Teste").Cells.Find("Total", , ,xlWhole).Column

Set columnsRange = Range(endcell, Range(endcell).End(xlDown)).Offset(1)
Dim cell As Range
Dim range_soma As Range
Dim cell_2 As Range



For Each cell In columnsRange
  If cell.Value = "" Then
        cell.Value = "Subtotal"

  ElseIf cell.Value = "Subtotal" Then

  ElseIf cell.Offset(1).Value <> cell.Value Then
        MsgBox "insere abaixo " & cell.Address
        cell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
        cell.Offset(1).Font.Bold = True
        cell.Offset(1).Value = "Subtotal"
        Range(cell.Offset(1, -2), cell.Offset(1, total - 4)).Interior.ColorIndex = 24

           For Each cell_2 In Range(cell.Offset(1, 1), cell.Offset(1, total - 4))
           cell_2.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[COUNT IF columnsRange = columnsRange*-1]C:R[-1]C)"
           Next cell_2
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

[image: Print da tabela]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma de inserir a fórmula com `.FormulaR1C1` é inserir uma fórmula de soma que vai da primeira célula anterior ao Subtotal até uma célula antes do Subtotal.

Isso pode ser realizado com a seguinte fórmula: `.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[" & (cell_2.Row - FirstRow) * -1 & "]C:R[-1]C)"`

Que no seu exemplo, no primeiro loop de cell_2, o valor de `cell_2.Row` é 8 e `FirstRow` é 2. Portanto a fórmula ficaria `.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-6]C:R[-1]C)"`, ou seja, realiza uma soma a partir de 6 linhas anteriores ao local em que a fórmula será inserida e termina na célula que é uma linha anterior, todos na mesma coluna.

#### Código

Segue o código completo:

```
Option Explicit
Sub criar_linha()

    Dim txt As String, endcell As String
    Dim total As Variant
    Dim columnsRange As Range

    txt = "Cliente"
    endcell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Teste").Cells.Find(txt, , , xlWhole).Address
    total = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Teste").Cells.Find("Total", , , xlWhole).Column

    Set columnsRange = Range(endcell, Range(endcell).End(xlDown)).Offset(1)
    
    Dim cell As Range, range_soma As Range, cell_2 As Range
    
    Dim IsFirstRow As Boolean
    Dim FirstRow As Long
    
    FirstRow = Range(endcell).Offset(1, 0).Row

    For Each cell In columnsRange
        'Verifica se é a primeira linha
        If IsFirstRow = True Then
            IsFirstRow = False
            FirstRow = cell.Row + 1
        End If
        
        If cell.Value = "" Then
            cell.Value = "Subtotal"

        ElseIf cell.Value = "Subtotal" Then

        ElseIf cell.Offset(1).Value <> cell.Value Then
            IsFirstRow = True
            'MsgBox "insere abaixo " & cell.Address
            cell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
            cell.Offset(1).Font.Bold = True
            cell.Offset(1).Value = "Subtotal"
            Range(cell.Offset(1, -2), cell.Offset(1, total - 4)).Interior.ColorIndex = 24

            For Each cell_2 In Range(cell.Offset(1, 1), cell.Offset(1, total - 4))
                cell_2.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[" & _
                                     (cell_2.Row - FirstRow) * -1 & _
                                     "]C:R[-1]C)"
            Next cell_2
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Daniel! Estava realmente travado nessa parte.